# An example of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $\tau(t)$ be a continuous real valued function, where $\lim_{t\rightarrow\mp \infty}\tau (t)$ is finite and nonzero, and $\inf_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \tau(t) > 0$.

Define

$$X=\left\{x\in \mathcal{C}^{1}(\mathbb{R},E): \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} \displaystyle\frac{\|x(t)\|}{\tau(t)}<\infty,\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\|x'(t)\|<\infty\right\}$$

My question is that can you prove $X$ is a Banach space with the norm

$$\|x\|_{X}=\max\left\{\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\|x(t)\|}{\tau(t)},\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\|x'(t)\|\right\}$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do we have a condition such as $\inf_{\mathbb R} \tau > 0$ ? Otherwise I take $\tau=-1$ and the result is false.

Comment: I am sorry. I denoted B wrongly. It must be E ,i.e.,E is the Banach space with the norm $\|.\|$.

Comment: Yes, i also have the condition that $\inf \tau>0$.

Comment: What exactly is $x'$?

Comment: $x'$ is a strong derivative

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Start with a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ in $X$. Prove that it is a Cauchy sequence in ${\cal C}^1([a, b], E)$ for any interval $[a, b]$. As this space is a Banach space there is a function $x$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in all the ${\cal C}^1([a, b], E)$. Prove that $\|x\|_X$ is finite (that's easy), so that $x \in X$.

Then consider the Cauchy sequence $y_n = x_n - x$. You know that it converges to $0$ in all the ${\cal C}^1([a, b], E)$. Try to prove that it converges to $0$ in $X$.

**Edit** The above procedure will work if one supposes $0 < \inf_{\mathbb R} \tau$ and $\sup_{\mathbb R} \tau < \infty$. Is it another missing hypothesis in the question? If $\tau$ is continuous, the latter is satisfied.

Comment: Sorry, $\tau$ is a continuous function. Is the result of $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ same for $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$. How can we proof that limit of a Cauchy sequence is in $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: ${\mathcal C}^1({\mathbb R})$ is not a Banach space, which makes your result doubtful.